# How to detect where there is a right-to-left mark in a UTF-8 string, Pyhton

Tags: python, string, utf-8, encode, right-to-left

I have a UTF-8 string and I want to detect if the bracket in the string is RTL or LTR (to understand if it's an opening or closing bracket)
I tried to print the characters - each one on a separate line, and if there is a right-to-left mark, print something like "---RLM---".

I am guessing I need to use encode/decode but I don't understand how to do that for that purpose...

```py
for char in text:
    print(char+'\n')
    if is_right_to_left_mark(char):
        print("right_to_left_mark"+'\n')
    elif is_left_to_right_mark(char):
        print("left_to_right_mark"+'\n')
```

Comment: How are is_right_to_left_mark and is_left_to_right_mark defined?

Comment: Please add the contents of `text` and `is_right_to_left_mark` + `is_left_to_right_mark`